# Ajax.BeginForm is loading a new page even with UpdateTargetId

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I did this right here:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UserProjMetric", "Users", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "dailyMetric" }))
                        {
                            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="@Model.Id"/>
                            <span class=""><input type="text" class="startDate dates" placeholder="Start Date" id="startDate" name="startDate"></span>
                            <span class=""><input type="text" class="endDate dates" placeholder="End Date" id="endDate" name="endDate"></span>
                            <input class="btn btn-small" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        }
```

But instead of updating the target id it just takes the entire partial and loads it on a new page.  I really just want the specific div on the page updated not the entire page.

I am returning a partial view:

```
return PartialView("_UserProjMetric", model);
```

Comment: Verify that you are actually returning a PartialView() from the controller. I think returning View() might induce this behaviour

Comment: Made edit above I am returning a partial view

Comment: Make sure you've control on page with Id "dailyMetric"

Comment: Make sure you're rendering `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` (which you can install using NuGet Id `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`).

Comment: Yep I have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: @allencoded, and is there an element on the page with id `dailyMetric`?

Comment: Yes there is. It is on my parent view this partial loads onto the page through that view.

Comment: I just rewrote the form using jquery $.post worked fine.

Comment: I've had this same exact problem before and it turned out to be missing scripts, so I'm highly suspicious of that.. are you sure you're not getting a 500 on a malformed relative path?

Comment: also, make sure you have `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>` in `<appSettings>` in your web.config

Comment: I had this same problem and it was because I was not rendering the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` on my page, just like @CarrieKendall said.